# What is the type of this haskell double function composition?

Tags: haskell, currying, lambda-calculus, function-composition

`t2 = (\x y z-> x.y.x)`

GHCI shows me this:

`t2 :: (b1 -> b2) -> (b2 -> b1) -> p -> b1 -> b2`

I can't quite grasp it how this type signature comes to be. So far I've figured that the righter-most x is basically a function which takes a `b2` and returns a `b1`, then that `b1` is the input of the middle function `y`, and outputs `b2`again? Should it not return a value of a new type `b3`or something?

Comment: the `.` operator only operates on functions (it is for function composition - that is, the result you get from first applying one function, then the other). So I don't see how you can think the return value of `t2` can be anything other than a function. (That's the `b1 -> b2` part at the end of the type signature GHC has derived.)

Comment: I see, but why (b1->b2), why not (b1->b3)? how does it know it has the same type as the output of the right x function

Comment: also, are you sure you didn't mean `x.y.z` on the right-hand side? It's strange to give it an argument `z` which isn't used at all to compute the function result. (GHC is giving this argument the type `p`, which as you will see, could be absolutely anything.)

Comment: because `x . y . x` means "apply `x` first, then apply `y` to the result, then apply `x` again to the result of that". If `x` has type `b1 -> b2`, then you need a `b1` to get the process started (because `x` is applied first), and the compound function must return a `b2` (because `x` is also applied last).

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes I was testing how and where unused parameters show up in the type signature. It is confusing to me why it shows up right after (b2->b1), and why are the types b1 and b2 applied after p? It's so confusing...

Comment: the `->` arrow in Haskell type signatures is right associative, meaning you can also read this type as `(b1 -> b2) -> (b2 -> b1) -> p -> (b1 -> b2)`. [This fact is just an alternative way of describing how all functions in Haskell are curried.] Looked at in this way, you can see that it takes 2 functions (the second of which maps from the target type of the first back to its source type) and one other argument of any type, and returns a function of the same type as the first argument. Hopefully you can see how this matches the explicit formula you've given for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let's rewrite this in a way that makes it clear which argument corresponds to which part of the type signature:

```
t2 :: (b1->b2) -> (b2->b1) -> p -> b1 -> b2
t2    x           y           z  = x . y . x
```

`z :: p` isn't used at all, so we can easily eliminate this by instead considering

```
t3 :: (b1->b2) -> (b2->b1) -> b1 -> b2
t3    x           y         = x . y . x
```

Why is that the type? Well, the composition chain feeds the result of `x` into `y`, and the result of `y` back into `x`. In other words, `y` gets you from the result type of `x` back to the argument type of `x`. Therefore the type of `y` must be the “inverted” type of `x`. So

```
t3 :: (m->n) -> (n->m) -> ?
t3    x         y       = x . y . x
```

The type of the composition is dominated by the “outer ends”, i.e. the argument must be the type of argument for `x` and the result must be the type of result of... again, `x`. Hence

```
t3 :: (m->n) -> (n->m) -> m->n
t3    x         y       = x.y.x
```

which is what GHCi told you, with renamed type variables.